# a['map'](b) how does this Javascript syntax work and what is it called?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = n => n + 5;
var wtf = 'map'

a[wtf](b);     // Array(3) [ 6, 7, 8 ]
a['map'](b);   // Array(3) [ 6, 7, 8 ]
```

I don't understand the general principle behind it and can't figure out what is it called so I can look it up.

Comment: You are dealing with `arrays` and `indexes`

Comment: Also you're dealing with *substituting* an `index`s nomenclature with a `variable` = `wtf`  - So since the variable `wtf` gets `'map'` --  There is no difference between the `array[index]` `a['map']` and `a[wtf]`  Since `wtf` is set to `'map'`

Comment: @Zak thank you! I think I got it!